How to suppress warning for all derived types?
I have an ITemplate interface in my project. All interfaces derived from it have names that do not start with I. This causes the InconsistentNaming warning to appear.
I want to suppress this warning for all interfaces derived from the ITemplate interface.
I know about SuppressMessage attribute, but it does not suppress warnings on the derived types. I tried to play around with Scope property of this attribute, but unfortunately nothing changed.
Basically, I want to do something like this:
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "InconsistentNaming", Target = Targets.Inheritors)]
public interface ITemplate;


You should be able to right click on the warning and suppress it. I'm not sure why you can't just use a class instead of another interface. Personally, I prefer the I prefix for interface names and most people that read your code will know what that means. But that's up to you I guess.

@JonathanWood I also use the I prefix for the interfaces, but interfaces derived from ITemplate are used only through reflection in my project, and their names is important. I can't use abstract classes because some templates must be derived from more than one other template

There is no way to suppress the Inconsistent Naming warning only for types deriving from a specific interface. There are a couple of other options.
pragma IDE1006
Use the pragma directive to suppress the warning within in an entire file. Place the following at the top of the file:
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Inconsistent naming

To re-enable the warning anywhere else in the file, add the following just above where the warning should be re-enabled:
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Inconsistent naming

.csproj NoWarn
To suppress the warning for an entire project, use the NoWarn property. Open up the .csproj in question and add the following:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Other properties -->
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);IDE1006</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Other project settings -->

</Project>


Thanks for the answer, but I want to suppress this warning forever, and not for the entire project.
